# Find $x(t) = \sum_k[(a_k)(t^k)]$ such that $tx'' = x'$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I'm taking an o.d.e. class and have tried working a practice problem a few times but am not sure how to interpret the recurrence relation I am getting.

I've represented $x''$ and $x'$ as series and re-indexed accordingly so that my sums for each term start at $1$ instead of $0$. This resulted in having an a_1 term alone, and I've found that $a_1 = 0$. However, this leaves me with the recurrence relation: $$(k)(k+1)(a_k+1) - (k+1)(a_k+1) = 0$$ And this simplifies to $k = 1$.

The answer is supposed to be that $a_1 = 0$ and $a_k = 0$ for all $k \geq 3$, leaving $$x(t) = a_0 + (a_2)t^2$$

I'm not sure if I've simply overlooked a simple arithmetic mistake or if I'm handling the recurrence relation improperly. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why can't you solve it using normal methods?

Comment: The problem specifically asks to solve it as a power series and this is the main method I've learned for such questions. What do you mean by normal methods?

Comment: If you have been solving every differential equation using this method, then it is time for you to learn more basic methods.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, our professor just wants us to use this method for the section we are currently covering. We have learned many other ways of solving these types of equations!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Normal method

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
tx'' &=& x' \\
t\dfrac{\mathrm dx'}{\mathrm dt} &=& x' \\
\dfrac{\mathrm dx'}{x'} &=& \dfrac{\mathrm dt}t \\
\displaystyle \int \dfrac{\mathrm dx'}{x'} &=& \displaystyle \int \dfrac{\mathrm dt}t \\
\ln x' &=& \ln t + C \\
x' &=& kt \\
\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt} &=& kt \\
\displaystyle \int \dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt} &=& \displaystyle \int kt \\
x &=& kt^2 + C \\
\end{array}$$

---

### Power series

$$\begin{array}{rrcl}
&x(t) &=& \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k t^k \\
&x'(t) &=& \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty k a_k t^{k-1} \\
&&=& \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1) a_{k+1} t^k \\
&x''(t) &=& \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)k a_{k+1} t^{k-1} \\
&tx''(t) &=& \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)k a_{k+1} t^k \\\\
&x'(t) &=& tx''(t) \\
&\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1) a_{k+1} t^k &=& \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty (k+1)k a_{k+1} t^k \\
&\displaystyle a_1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty (k+1) a_{k+1} t^k &=& \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty (k+1)k a_{k+1} t^k \\
\forall k \ge 1: & (k+1) a_{k+1} &=& (k+1)k a_{k+1} \\
\forall k \ge 1: & (k+1)(1-k) a_{k+1} &=& 0 \\
\forall k \ge 1: & a_{k+1} &=& 0 &\text{ or }k = 1 \\
\end{array}$$

And $a_1=0$.

When $k \ne 0,2$, $a_k = 0$, which leaves $a_0$ and $a_2$ arbitrary.

---

### Your mistake

You correctly obtained:
$$(k)(k+1)(a_{k+1}) - (k+1)(a_{k+1}) = 0$$

But you failed to notice that this is an identity, which is true for all $k$. Instead, you tried to find $k$ from here. The fact that $k=1$ only means that $a_2$ is arbitrary. **For other values of $k$, $a_{k+1}$ has to be 0.**